# What are some good practical halacha audio shiurim I can find online?

Tags: halacha, product-recommendation, internet, adult-learning

Does anyone know of good shiurim and preferably ongoing series of good audio shiurim on halacha that are available online?

I'm preferably looking for something:

- Practice-level.
- Relevant to everyday life (i.e. Hilchos Shabbos as opposed to Hilchos Eidus).
- By someone who is qualified. (Can be subjective, I know.)
- Archived is fine, but even better would be ongoing. Even better is if it has an rss feed.

Please indicate in your answer how your recommendation fits with these criteria, and why you recommend it, in particular.

Answer (score 7):

http://www.yutorah.org/ has halacha shiurim on a huge range of topics, both in depth and very practical. Just click on the "halacha" tab. Highly recommended.

Also http://www.kolhaloshon.com/, from the more yeshivish side of things, with lots of shiurim from R' Osher Arieli and other Ram"im in the MIr Yeshiva.

Comment: And they have RSS feeds!

Comment: The question was halacha shiurim. If its gemoro you want you will do better with an artscroll.

Answer (score 5):

www.dailyhalacha.com by Rabbi Monsour is my favorite. It is relevant to everyday life. It is delivered by Rabbi Monsour who is truly qualified. It is available daily and also has archives of previous days.

Answer (score 4):

R. Aryeh Lebowitz on Yutorah has hundreds of excellent (and usually short) halacha shiurim.
See them [here](http://www.yutorah.org/Rabbi_Aryeh_Lebowitz).

Answer (score 2):

Rabbi Nissan Kaplan has some excellent mishna berura shiurim on hilchos shabbos [here](http://ravkaplan.dafyomireview.com/cd.php?cdall=Halacha/Mishna_Berura_Chelek_3-amudY)
and now on chelek aleph also http://ravkaplan.dafyomireview.com/index.php?all=1&dir=Mishna-Berura

Comment: I believe mishnaberurahyomi.org also has recorded shiurim available in their Archive section.

Answer (score 1):

Rav Shlomo Pearl is very good. He is very relevant and brings many sources and most of his shiurim consist of actual questions asked of him.I believe he is very well versed in Hilchos Shabbas and he focuses alot on it,but he talks about all relevant topics,shabbas ,davening,Yom tov,shidduchim,yichud...

http://www.torahanytime.com/speakers/speaker-detail-listview/?id=70

Comment: How does he match up to the requirements listed in the question?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.businesshalacha.com/ has many shiurim and a shailah hotline among other great services

Answer (score 1):

Rabbi Ari Kahn has a series of halacha shiurim which he puts online. It is ongoing but they get uploaded in spurts - every few months a few months of shiurim are uploaded. There's also archives. Each shiur is about an hour long and goes through all the relevant sources to show different opinions and perspectives. He also tries to keep them relevant to current events on occasion, however since the uploads often don't happen for a few months, that isn't always a help.

- [his homepage](http://rabbiarikahn.com/audios?id=1)
- [iTunes link](https://itunes.apple.com/il/podcast/rabbi-ari-kahn-halacha-shiurim/id612367724?mt=2)

Answer (score 1):

[Rabbi Eliezer Krohn's shiurim on TorahAnytime.com](http://www.torahanytime.com/speakers-list/rabbi-eliezer-krohn/) cover the full gamut of practical Halacha. He has over 200 of them. It's a lot of Hilchos Shabbos, but also includes Brachos, Bein Adam L'chaveiro, Tefillah, Kashrut - really a pretty thorough list of practical Halacha topics. They are mostly given to groups of women, so they are very practical but don't delve into the theoretical sugyos. The shiurim are ongoing (I believe he posts several a week.)